# IEEE 754 rounding or chopping

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

Who and at what stage one decide to use chopping or rounding a number? For example if I write a C program and there is a `double` variable in it then what happens to the number `2.57` (regardless of its floating point representation)? Is it chopped to `2.5` or rounded to `2.6`? Does my C compiler decide between these two possibility? Does IEEE 754 standard say what my C compiler should do? Is it implemented in my CPU architecture or maybe my OS?

Answer (score 3):

It's implementation-defined. Specifically, although commonly used, C standard doesn't enforce IEEE-754 support.

> #### C11 §6.4.4.2 *Floating constants* section3
>
> The significand part is interpreted as a (decimal or hexadecimal) rational number; the digit sequence in the exponent part is interpreted as a decimal integer. For decimal floating constants, the exponent indicates the power of 10 by which the significand part is to be scaled. For hexadecimal floating constants, the exponent indicates the power of 2 by which the significand part is to be scaled. For decimal floating constants, and also for hexadecimal floating constants when `FLT_RADIX` is not a power of 2, **the result is either the nearest representable value, or the larger or smaller representable value immediately adjacent to the nearest representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner.** For hexadecimal floating constants when `FLT_RADIX` is a power of 2, the result is correctly rounded.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by @YuHao C standard does not enforce [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) conformance, but there is pre-defined macro for checking that. Reference N1570 §6.10.8.3/p1, *Conditional feature macros*:

> `__STDC_IEC_559__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate conformance to the specifications in annex F (IEC 60559 floating-point
>   arithmetic).
>
> `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate adherence to the specifications in annex G (IEC 60559
>   compatible complex arithmetic)

As you can find out it's effectively the same standard as IEEE-754.

These macros are also (conditionally) defined in C99 (N1256 §6.10.8/p2).